# will signing out of icloud delete all my notes permanently?

Tags: icloud, restore, login, notes.app, data-recovery

I am supposed to, as part of troubleshooting my iCloud account error messages, sign  out of icloud then back in.
I get the pop-up that logging out will remove all the Notes from my mac.

When i log back in, will my Notes be restored to my mac?

Answer (score 3):

You should be fine. Refer to: [If you sign out of iCloud](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH25735?) to get a better understanding of what will happen with your documents and data (including photos. etc).

However, if you're concerned and you have another device (such as an iPhone or iPad), you can ensure they are logged into your iCloud account so you can see/access the notes on those devices.

And of course, it goes without saying that you should ensure you have a backup regime in place (such as using [Time Machine](https://support.apple.com/en-sg/HT201250)).